# pushforward of affines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules

Suppose $A\rightarrow B$ is a morphism of rings (commutative with unit, not necc. Noetherian) and $f: \rm{Spec}\; B\rightarrow \rm{Spec} \;A$ the canonical morphism of schemes. Is it true that $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\rm{Spec}\; B} = \mathcal{O}_{\rm{Spec} \;B}$ where the right-hand side is regarded as an $\mathcal{O}_{\rm{Spec}\; A}$-module? The global sections of $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\rm{Spec}\; B}$ would then be equal to $\mathcal{O}_{\rm{Spec}\; B}(\rm{Spec}\;B) = B$ regarded as an $A$-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for any continuous map $f : X \to Y$ and any sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$, there is a natural bijection between $\Gamma (Y, f_* \mathscr{F})$ and $\Gamma (X, \mathscr{F})$, by definition of $f_* \mathscr{F}$. So indeed global sections of $f_* \mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B}$ are just elements of $B$.

Next, let $a$ be any element of $A$ and consider the distinguished open subset $D (a) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} A$. It is not hard to check that the preimage $f^{-1} D (a)$ is just $D (b) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} B$, where $b$ is the image of $a$ in $B$. Thus, $\Gamma (D (a), f_* \mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B})$ is (naturally isomorphic to) $B [b^{-1}]$. But $B [b^{-1}] \cong A [a^{-1}] \otimes_A B$, and $\{ D (a) : a \in A \}$ is a basis for the topology of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, so we deduce that $f_* \mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B}$ is indeed (isomorphic to) the $\mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}$-module $\tilde{B}$.